# Compute the norm of the operator $A$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let the operator $A: X \rightarrow X(X=\{f \in C([0,3]) ; f(3)=0\})$ be given by the the formula

$$
(A f)(x)=(x+5) f(x)
$$

Compute the norm of the operator $A$.

I have done the following to solve the problem:

1. Define the operator $A$: The operator $A$ is defined as $(Af)(x)=(x+5)f(x)$ for all $f\in X$, where $X$ is the set of all continuous functions on the interval $[0,3]$ that satisfy $f(3)=0$.
2. Define the norm of a function: The norm of a function $f\in X$ is defined as $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in[0,3]}|f(x)|$, which is the maximum absolute value of $f(x)$ over the interval $[0,3]$.
3. Define the norm of the operator $A$: The norm of the operator $A$ is defined as $\|A\|=\sup_{f\neq 0}\frac{\|Af\|}{\|f\|}$, which is the supremum (least upper bound) of the ratios $\frac{\|Af\|}{\|f\|}$ for all non-zero functions $f\in X$.
4. Compute the norm of $Af$: For each $f\in X$, we have $\|Af\|=\sup_{x\in[0,3]}|(x+5)f(x)|$. Since $f(3)=0$, the function $f$ attains its maximum at some $x_0\in[0,3)$. Therefore, $\|Af\|=\sup_{x\in[0,3)}|(x+5)f(x)|$.
5. Compute the ratio $\frac{\|Af\|}{\|f\|}$: Since $f$ is not the zero function, the denominator $\|f\|$ is not zero. Therefore, we can compute the ratio $\frac{\|Af\|}{\|f\|}=\frac{\sup_{x\in[0,3)}|(x+5)f(x)|}{\sup_{x\in[0,3)}|f(x)|}$.
6. Compute the supremum of the ratios: Finally, we compute $\|A\|=\sup_{f\neq 0}\frac{\|Af\|}{\|f\|}=\sup_{x\in[0,3)}|x+5|=8$.

So, the norm of the operator $A$ is $8$.

Was this a good idea to solve the problem?

Comment: It's not that simple. You can't cancel $|f(x)|$ in the last step like this. Supremum is not multiplicative. The term $\sup_{x\in [0,3)} |(x+5)f(x)|$ is a bit more complicated than just $8\sup|f|$. My suggestion: first show that $||A||\leq 8$, this is relatively simple. Then show the reverse inequality by choosing specific functions $f$ for which the ratio $\frac{||Af||}{||f||}$ is more than $8-\epsilon$.

Comment: First: Show that $\|A\|\leq8$: For any $f\in X$, we have
$$\|Af\|=\sup_{x\in[0,3]}|(x+5)f(x)|\leq\sup_{x\in[0,3]}|8f(x)|=8\|f\|.$$
So, $\|A\|\leq8$.

Comment: Secondly: Show that $\|A\|\geq8-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$: Choose $f_\epsilon(x)=\frac{3-x}{3}\chi_{[0,3-\epsilon]}(x)$, where $\chi_{[0,3-\epsilon]}$ is the characteristic function of the interval $[0,3-\epsilon]$. Then $f_\epsilon\in X$ and
$$\frac{\|Af_\epsilon\|}{\|f_\epsilon\|}=\frac{\sup_{x\in[0,3-\epsilon]}|(x+5)f_\epsilon(x)|}{\sup_{x\in[0,3-\epsilon]}|f_\epsilon(x)|}\geq\frac{|(3-\epsilon+5)f_\epsilon(3-\epsilon)|}{|f_\epsilon(3-\epsilon)|}=8-\epsilon.$$
Taking the supremum over all such $f_\epsilon$, we get $\|A\|\geq8-\epsilon$.

Comment: Therefore, by letting $\epsilon$ go to zero, we can conclude that $\|A\|=8$. What do you think?

Comment: The problem is that the functions $f_\varepsilon(x)$ that you have defined are not continuous on the whole interval $[0,3]$, so they can't be in $X$. I'll write a full answer with the solution.

Comment: That's pretty close. Though note that your $f_{\epsilon}$ is not continuous. Instead of making it zero everywhere outside of $[0,3-\epsilon]$, take it linearly to $0$. By the way, not sure why you need the fraction $\frac{3-x}{3}$. It's easier to define $f_{\epsilon}\equiv 1$ in $[0,3-\epsilon]$, and then in $[3-\epsilon, 3]$ take it linearly down to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult to prove that if $h,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ are two continuous functions with $g(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ then $\sup(hg)\leq\sup(\sup(h)g)$. So for all $f\in X\setminus\{0\}$: $$\frac{\|Af\|}{\|f\|}=\frac{\sup|x+5||f(x)|}{\sup|f(x)|}\leq\frac{\sup(8|f(x)|)}{\sup|f(x)|}=8\:\Longrightarrow\:\|A\|=\sup_{f\neq 0}\frac{\|Af\|}{\|f\|}\leq 8$$
Now, assuggested by Mark, for $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 1}$, consider the function: $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:x\in\left[0,3-\frac{1}{n}\right]\\n(3-x)\:\:\:\:\:\:\:x\in\left[3-\frac{1}{n},3\right]\end{cases}$$ which is continuous on $[0,3]$ and $f_n(3)=0$ (so $f_n\in X$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 1}$).
Some simple calculations show that: $$\|f_n\|=\sup_{x\in[0,3]}|f_n(x)|=1$$ and $$\|Af_n\|=\sup_{x\in[0,3]}|(x+5)f_n(x)|=(x+5)f_n(x)|_{x=3-\frac{1}{n}}=8-\frac{1}{n}$$
At this point: $$8-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{\|Af_n\|}{\|f_n\|}\leq\sup_{f\in X\setminus\{0\}}\frac{\|Af\|}{\|f\|}=\|A\|\leq 8$$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 1}$, which implies that $\|A\|=8$.